# Prove that every module has a cover from the class of torsion modules

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, modules, homological-algebra

[image: Definition of an F- cover]I am having trouble with the last part of this proof from Relative Homological Algebra by Jenda and Enoch. I was hoping someone could check my work, and give me hint for the last part of the proof. The complete question goes as follows:

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $\mathcal{F}$ be the class of torsion $R$-modules. Show that every $R$-module has an $\mathcal{F}$-cover that is an injection.

Here is what I have so far.

We begin by noting that $Tor(M)$ is a sub-module of any $R$-module $M$. We claim that the cover can be given by
$$\iota : Tor(M) \to M, \quad x \mapsto x$$
The second condition is fairly straightforward to prove. Let $\phi: Tor(M)\mapsto Tor(M)$ be a homomorphism such that $\iota \circ\phi = \iota$. Then for $m \in Tor(M)$, if $\phi(m) = 0$, then
$$(\iota \circ \phi)(m) =\iota(\phi(m)) = \iota(m) = m= 0$$
Shows that $\phi$ injects, and so it must be an automorphism.

The part I am having trouble with is showing that for any $T \in \mathcal{F}$, a commutative diagram with $\iota$ can be given.

Comment: Hint: Better don't write an inclusion as an identity. It is not an identity. You can use any letter, but $\iota$ is quite common.

Comment: Also you will get more answers when you specify the diagram you are referring to in the last paragraph. Or link to a source where it is shown. Then more people understand the problem.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you, I uploaded the picture, and I will update the notation when I have a bit more time.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I will switch out the notation, thanks! I am a bit confused at the hint though. What about it being an inclusion vs. an identity map is relevant?

Comment: Thanks for adding the diagram. The distinction between inclusion and identity map is relevant, because, well, the inclusion map is not an identity map. An identity map has equal source and target. The inclusion map does not. This is why it is misleading to denote it as $\mathrm{id}$. I have edited the notation in your post.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thank you, I will stick to this convention moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the second condition is not complete. You only show that $\phi$ is injective, but you need to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. But actually, $\phi = \mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Tor}(M)}$ follows immediately from $\iota = \iota \circ \phi$, since $\iota$ is injective. And surely the identity is an automorphism.

The first condition is also easy to prove. If $f : N \to M$ is a homomorphism, where $N$ is torsion, we need to find a homomorphism $f' : N \to \mathrm{Tor}(M)$ with $\iota \circ f' = f$. In other words, we need to show $f(N) \subseteq \mathrm{Tor}(M)$. But if $n \in N$, then $rn = 0$ for some $0 \neq r \in R$ (since $N$ is torsion), hence $r f(n) = f(rn) = 0$, and we see that $f(n)$ is torsion.

Comment: I initially thought the definition was suggesting that every $C' \in \mathcal{F}$ had to have a homomorphism into $C$, but I think your proof helped me see that this is probably not true right? Instead I only need to show that this is true for all objects in the class with a homomorphism into $M$ right? That actually makes much more sense.

So I don't need to show that the diagram commutes for every element in the class of objects, but that IF a $C' \in \mathcal{F}$ has a homomorphic map to $M$, that you could then define a map $C' \mapsto C$ that satisfies (1)?